# How can I get GCC to optimize this bit-shifting instruction into a move?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-optimization, bit-fields

I'm trying to use the following code to emulate a 16-bit half-float in software:

```
typedef struct half
{
    unsigned short mantissa:10;
    unsigned short exponent:5;
    unsigned short sign:1;
} half;

unsigned short from_half(half h)
{
    return h.mantissa | h.exponent << 10 | h.sign << 15;
}

half to_half(unsigned short s)
{
    half result = { s, s >> 10, s >> 15 };
    return result;
}
```

I set this up so that it could easily be optimized into a move instruction, but lo and behold, in `from_half`, GCC does the bit-shifting anyway (even at `-O3`):

```
from_half:
        mov     edx, edi
        mov     eax, edi
        and     di, 1023
        shr     dx, 15
        and     eax, 31744
        movzx   edx, dl
        sal     edx, 15
        or      eax, edx
        or      eax, edi
        ret
```

while `to_half` is optimized nicely:

```
to_half:
        mov     eax, edi
        ret
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/AG7V3e)

I've tried different optimization levels (`-O1`, `-O2`, `-Os`) but none optimize it into what I was hoping.

Clang does this how I would expect even at `-O1`:

```
from_half:                              # @from_half
        mov     eax, edi
        ret
to_half:                                # @to_half
        mov     eax, edi
        ret
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/wt4EwJ)

How can I get GCC to optimize this into a move? Why isn't it optimized that way already?

Comment: Even for to_half, the optimization happens very late in gcc. You could look for bugs related to bitfields in gcc's bugzilla.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Took a look, none of the open ones are similar.

Comment: Please open one then...

Comment: @MarcGlisse https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=94086

Comment: One thing to note: There is no defined order of the 'bit' fields.  for instance, that single sign bit might be bit 0 or might be bit 15.  The actual order is implementation dependent

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to [Booboo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60580818/5218277), you can try the following which answers your question

> How can I get GCC to optimize this into a move?

Just cast each shifted bit-field expression to `unsigned short`

```
unsigned short from_half(half h)
{
    return (unsigned short)h.mantissa | (unsigned short)(h.exponent << 10) | (unsigned short)(h.sign << 15);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/CfZSgC

It results in:

```
from_half:
        mov     eax, edi
        ret
```

> Why isn't it optimized that way already?

I am not sure I have a solid answer on this one. Apparently the intermediate promotion of the bit-fields to `int` confuses the optimizer... But this is just a guess.

Comment: Thank you. Those casts are ugly but they do produce the desired result. See my [bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=94086) for updates (none yet).

Comment: @S.S.Anne I hope they fix it and won’t close as not a bug.

Comment: They won't. Generally tree-optimizations are taken seriously. They might take a while, though.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since I have coded in `C`, but it seems the use of a `union` should work:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static bool useUnion;

__attribute__ ((__constructor__)) // supported by gcc compiler
static void initUseUnion()
{
    union {
       uint16_t i;
       char c[2];
    } n = { 0x0001 };
    useUnion = n.c[0]; // little endian
}

typedef struct half
{
    unsigned short mantissa:10;
    unsigned short exponent:5;
    unsigned short sign:1;
} half;

typedef union half_short
{
    half h;
    uint16_t s;
} half_short;

unsigned short from_half(half h)
{
    if (useUnion) {
        half_short hs;
        hs.h = h;
        return hs.s;
    }
    else {
        return h.mantissa | h.exponent << 10 | h.sign << 15;
    }
}

half to_half(unsigned short s)
{
    if (useUnion) {
        half_short hs;
        hs.s = s;
        return hs.h;
    }
    else {
        half result = { s, s >> 10, s >> 15 };
        return result;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf("%d\n", useUnion);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is at best not portable. I might as well use `memcpy` if I was going to type-pun with a `union`. And note that in the question I didn't depend on the order of the fields.

Comment: You are, of course, right. But don't you think `to_half` was nicely optimized by your compiler solely because in your particular implementation the order of the fields neatly aligned with the the byte order of the `short`? Maybe you are hoping for or *depending* on too much. At the risk of getting myself deeper in a hole, I have locally modified my answer to test for big/little endian in initialization code to set a `useUnion` variable that can be tested to determine whether or not a union should be used. Is it worth updating the answer (the union is better than using memcpy)?

Comment: My point about "depending on too much" was hinting that the big/little "endianess" of different platforms might very well impede your ability to do this for all targets in a portable way.

Comment: True. I'll have to find a better way to do this. I still wonder why GCC misses it, though.

Comment: I would appreciate seeing the edit if you still have it.

Comment: the code posted in the answer causes the `gcc` compiler to output several messages about conversion between `int` and `unsigned int` and about the returned type from `main()` not being 'int`

Comment: @user3629249  As I said, it's been a while since I have coded in `C` and I have a *very* old version of `gcc` (4.6.3), which is obviously very forgiving. I got no warnings, but I have changed the return type for `main`.

Comment: If you want to install a newer GCC version I might be able to help you.

Comment: My gcc is part of a MinGW installation under Windows. Let me see if I can figure out how to do this if there is a later one available for that installation or how to install a standalone version. But thanks.

Comment: MinGW is old. You should use MinGW-w64. [This](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/mingw-builds/8.1.0/threads-posix/seh/x86_64-8.1.0-release-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0.7z/download) is the tarball I use (warning: download link).

Comment: That seems to be gcc 8.1.0 and generates no warnings either. It turns out I have two MinGW installations (now 3, I guess). gcc 4.6.3 came from a Perl installation which was ahead of my actual MinGW (gcc 6.3.0) installation in my system's PATH.